# How to collect all array unique values from array of objects using underscore?

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js

I have an array of objects. Like

```
    project=[
        {
            name : "A"
            dept : ["a", "b", "c"]
        },
        {
            name : "B"
            dept : ["a", "e", "f", "g"]
        },
        {
            name : "C"
            dept : ["b", "c", "e", "j"]
        },
    ]
```

Now I want to collect all unique array values of dept from this array of object using underscore.
The output should be save in a new array. Like

```
var newArray = ["a", "b", "c", "e", "f", "g", "j"]
```

I am new in underscore.js. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can flatten the all arrays dept and get the _uniq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var project = [{
    name: "A",
    dept: ["a", "b", "c"]
}, {
    name: "B",
    dept: ["a", "e", "f", "g"]
}, {
    name: "C",
    dept: ["b", "c", "e", "j"]
}, ]



_UNIQUEAGEARRAY = _.flatten(project.map(function(item) {
    return item.dept
}));

console.log(_.uniq(_UNIQUEAGEARRAY));

document.body.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(_UNIQUEAGEARRAY);
```

A Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/7k3ewb49/

Comment: Goodness. Exactly what I want. Thanks a lot Thalaivar.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
_.uniq(_.flatten(project.map(x => x.dept)));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Set` and `reduce()` to do this in pure js.

```js
var project = [{
  name: "A",
  dept: ["a", "b", "c"]
}, {
  name: "B",
  dept: ["a", "e", "f", "g"]
}, {
  name: "C",
  dept: ["b", "c", "e", "j"]
}];

var result = [...new Set(project.reduce((r, e) => r.concat(e.dept), []))]
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution using underscore's [**pluck**](http://underscorejs.org/#pluck), [**flatten**](http://underscorejs.org/#flatten) and [**uniq**](http://underscorejs.org/#uniq):

```
var result = _.chain(project)
    .pluck('dept')
    .flatten()
    .uniq()
    .value();
```

```js
   var  project=[
        {
            name : "A",
            dept : ["a", "b", "c"]
        },
        {
            name : "B",
            dept : ["a", "e", "f", "g"]
        },
        {
            name : "C",
            dept : ["b", "c", "e", "j"]
        },
    ]

    var result = _.chain(project)
     .pluck('dept')
     .flatten()
     .uniq()
     .value();
        
document.getElementById('result').textContent = JSON.stringify(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>

<p>
  <pre id="result"></pre>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

ES2015 version:

```
const newArray = project.reduce((res, {dept}) => 
    (dept.forEach(v => !res.some(r => r === v) && res.push(v)), res), []);
```

also

```
const newArray = [...new Set(Array.prototype.concat.apply([], project.map(({dept}) => dept)))]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This.

```js
var projects = [{
  name: "A",
  dept: ["a", "b", "c"]
}, {
  name: "B",
  dept: ["a", "e", "f", "g"]
}, {
  name: "C",
  dept: ["b", "c", "e", "j"]
}]

var depts = [];

projects.map((project) => {
  depts = depts.concat(project.dept)
});

var result = depts.filter((item, pos) => depts.indexOf(item) == pos);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) `...` and [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set)

```js
var project = [{ name: "A", dept: ["a", "b", "c"] }, { name: "B", dept: ["a", "e", "f", "g"] }, { name: "C", dept: ["b", "c", "e", "j"] }];

var result = project.reduce((r, a) => [...new Set([...r, ...a.dept])], []);
console.log(result);
```